# Argument out of range exception

Tags: .net

i want to concate title in url for the corresponding id but it is giving Argument out of range exception.

Please Help,

```
     Dim unqidstr As String = Request.QueryString("id").ToString()
        unqidstr = unqidstr.Substring(0, unqidstr.IndexOf("-"))
        Dim x As String = "select unqid, title, img, Ttl_desc from Schedule_Master_AYS where unqid ='" + unqidstr + "'"

        'Dim cmd As SqlCommand("",


        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt = Dal.GettDS(x).Tables(0)
        x = ""
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            x += "<h2>'" + dr("title") + "' </h2>"
            x += "<p>'" + dr("Ttl_desc") + "'</p>"
            x += "<br />"
            x += "<br />"
            x += "<img src='" + dr("img").ToString().Replace("~/", "") + "' style='margin-left: 100px; width:400px;' />"
        Next
        x = x.Replace("'", """")
        divTTC.InnerHtml = x
```

Answer (score 2):

`Substring` throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when the length argument is less than zero, so that's my guess.

You have this line,

```
unqidstr = unqidstr.Substring(0, unqidstr.IndexOf("-"))
```

And my suspicion is that `unqidstr` doesn't have a hyphen in it. You probably want to explicitly check for that `IndexOf` to return a number greater than `-1` before calling `Substring`.

Comment: okk... but i am refrencing id including hyphen and title from other page. Dim x As String = "select Title,'TTCTraining.aspx?id='+convert(nvarchar,unqid)+'-'+replace(title,' ','-') as url, TTCFeeOnly,TTCFeeAccomodation Registration from Schedule_Master_AYS"

Comment: ok i fixed it. hyphen was the problem.. thanku so much... but how will i concate hyphen and title with unqidstr as i want "id-title" in url..

Answer (score 0):

You must check if the value returned by the querystring is not null, ir not continue with the rest of the algorithm